# WordPress: Disable singular pages when creating a Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I've created a few Custom Post Types for my site. And some of them shouldn't have a viewable page in the front-end.

I saw, that there is an argument to prevent archives for Custom Post Types:

```php
'has_archive' => false,
```

Is there anything like this for single front-end pages?

At the moment I create a `301` redirect for these Custom Post Types:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'theme_redirects', 99 );

function theme_redirects() {
    if ( is_singular( 'post_type' ) ) {
     wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
         die();
  }
}
```

But for me, that's not an ideal situation.

Is there anything I could do instead of the redirects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `publicly_queryable` option. It's the same as the `has_archive` option, but for single posts.

Simply add this to your CPT config:

```
'publicly_queryable' => false
```